# How to correctly manage resource ownership when using range::views?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am currently reading about the `range` library. My question is about resource ownerships when using `views`, and how to use these safely.

Let's consider the following code, which print the even year in reverse order:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

auto print = [](auto elem) -> void {    std::cout << "  " << elem <<"," << std::endl; };
auto isEven = [](size_t year) -> bool {return !(year % 2);};

int main() {

    auto years = std::vector<size_t>{
        1998,        2003,        2011,        2014,
        2017,        2020,        2023};  

    auto view = years | 
        std::ranges::views::filter(isEven) | 
        std::ranges::views::reverse ;

    std::ranges::for_each(view, print);
}
```

Now, consider the following refactoring, where the view is created with a function:

```
#...

auto createViewOnEvenYears() {
    auto years = std::vector<size_t>{
        1998,        2003,        2011,        2014,
        2017,        2020,        2023};  

    auto view = years | 
        std::ranges::views::filter(isEven) | 
        std::ranges::views::reverse ;

    return view;
}

int main() {
    auto view = createViewOnEvenYears();
    std::cout << "Printing after vector destruction: " << std::endl;
    std::ranges::for_each(view, print);
}
```

As the vector has been destroyed when iterating on the view, this lead to a SEGFAULT.

My questions are:

- are `view` compatible with the Resource Acquisition Is Initialization principle?
- Should my function return the range adaptor to prevent this (as proposed below)?
- More generally, what design pattern(s) should I use to avoid `dangling views`?

```
std::vector<size_t> createYears() {
    return std::vector<size_t>{
        1998,        2003,        2011,        2014,
        2017,        2020,        2023};  
}

auto createEvenReverseRangeAdaptor() {
    return 
        std::ranges::views::filter(isEven) | 
        std::ranges::views::reverse ;
}

int main() {
    auto years = createYears();
    std::ranges::for_each(years | createEvenReverseRangeAdaptor(), print);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to `std::move` the vector into the pipeline:

```
auto view = std::move(years) | 
    std::ranges::views::filter(isEven) | 
    std::ranges::views::reverse ;
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f933c2d6dc64e6)

There's an implicit [`std::ranges::views::all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view) applied<sup>1</sup> to the leftmost argument of the pipeline, which treats lvalue and rvalue non-view ranges differently. It will wrap an lvalue in [`ref_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ref_view) and an rvalue in [`owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view).

<sup>1</sup> From the deduction guide

```
template< class R, class Pred >
filter_view( R&&, Pred ) -> filter_view<views::all_t<R>, Pred>;
```

Comment: I'm using C++17 (clang) and Eric Niebler's range-v3 library.  Appears `std::move(years)` doesn't work for range-v3.  Is there an equivalent operation for range-v3?

Comment: @Eljay You need to implement something like owning_view if it isn't there

Comment: I don't think it's in range-v3.  Drat.  Thanks for the `owning_view` tip, that'll give me enough to work with!